# Get average of a child column, but from filtered parent data in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

If I have a one-to-many relationship (where a parent can have many children) like so:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates='children')
```

I want all children whose parents have `70 < score < 100`, and of those children, I want the average of all their `data`.

I know I can get all the children with:

```
childs = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.score > 70, Parent.score < 100)

for c in childs:
    # calculate the average 'data' here...
```

But this is probably not efficient and is very manual way of calculating the average child data.

I know there is this way of getting an average of a table:

```
 session.query(func.avg(Child.data))
```

But how can I tie this into the above query where I filter on the parent's score?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just apply the same filters as in the other query:

```
 session.query(func.avg(Child.data)).filter(Child.parent.score > 70, Child.parent.score < 100)
```